# Why to use StringBuffer in Dart instead of Iterable.join?

Tags: dart

In Dart, you can concatenate Strings effectively by two ways: you can use StringBuffer class and then convert it to the String, or you can put all of your substrings into the List and then call join('') on them.

I do not understand, what are the pluses of the StringBuffer and why should I use it instead of joining List. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't a big difference. If you already have a list of strings, there is no difference in using `StringBuffer.writeAll` or `Iterable.join`. The `Iterable.join` method uses a `StringBuffer` internaly:

```
String join([String separator = ""]) {
 StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
 buffer.writeAll(this, separator);
 return buffer.toString();
}
```

From the [Dart documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-core/Iterable/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer is more efficient as it doesn't create a string object until you call toString.

Seth Lad blogged about the benefits [here](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/01/strings-in-dart.html) with some numbers to back it up.

There is a similar blog post about this [here](http://shailen.github.io/blog/2012/11/13/string-concatenation-in-dart/).

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to my question. I do understand, that StringBuffer is more efficient than using `+` to concatenate, but the question asks about `Iterable.join` vs `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but it might still help some people (just like me who came here while trying to eke out the most from these builders). I saw rather significant speedups with custom built string buffers like these:

If you can afford an upper capacity limit (no range checking, add if needed):

```
class StringBuilder {
  List<int> str;
  int position = 0;

  StringBuilder(int capacity) {
    str = List<int>(capacity);
  }

  void clear() {
    position = 0;
  }

  @override
  String toString() => String.fromCharCodes(str, 0, position);

  void write(String s) {
    for (int ch in s.codeUnits) str[position++] = ch;
  }

  void writeCharCode(int ch) {
    str[position++] = ch;
  }
}
```

If you can't:

```
class StringBuilder {
  List<int> str;

  StringBuilder() {
    str = <int>[];
  }

  void clear() {
    str.clear();
  }

  @override
  String toString() => String.fromCharCodes(str);

  void write(String s) {
    str.addAll(s.codeUnits);
  }

  void writeCharCode(int ch) {
    str.add(ch);
  }
}
```

I used them in format converters that have to do quite a lot of string manipulation (think XML parsing and similar) and it really helps. It those cases, it gets called repeatedly tens or hundreds of thousand of times and I could reduce the whole parsing time to around half in a specific case.